# How to redownload Unity dependencies from asset store, automatically?

Tags: unity-game-engine, dependency-management, package-managers

How can I download all dependencies of a Unity project, when getting it from version control?

Assuming that I have a few assets/packages from the Unity Asset Store, can I have them ignored by git / other VCS, but still have them download and install if missing?
I tried using unity's package manager, but I can't figure out if it has that capability (yet, as they seem to be planning to add it).

In other platforms, package managers like `npm`, `nuget`, `pip`, `maven` etc have *exactly the functionality that I'm looking for*. Is there something similar for unity projects?

---

I have tried having my codebase separate from Unity, and building a .dll and importing it in Unity to circumvent that situation, but it's not always feasible.

Comment: I guess the simplest answer to `How can I download all dependencies of a Unity project, when getting it from version control?` would be: **Upload everything required to the version control.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asset-Store items that download into your Assets folder can't do this, you need to delete and re-download/import them.

As of Unity 2018.2, there is now a **Package Manager** feature which *does* support this, but you'll need to wait for your Asset authors to publish their packages to the new system.

Comment: Thank you, I was unsure about the "authors needing to update" part.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Somehow I read your question as relating to *updating* Asset packages that you already have in your repo.  derHugo's answer in the OP comments is absolutely correct, store everything in your repo.

Answer (score 0):

The current set of features comes with a lof of drawback, so I've written up all my thoughts on this topic and sent it to Unity. You can read that here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/adding-a-dependency-to-an-asset-store-product-in-a-projects-manifest-json.1108304/#post-8608380

Please check that forum and add your thoughts if you'd like Unity to take it a bit more seriously. ;)

You can open the **Submitted idea** section there to see what I already sent to Unity.